# Accessing the shadowed field from enclosed member class (Java)

Tags: java, field, inner-classes

is it possible to access a shadowed field of an enclosing class from the enclosed one in Java?

```
public class Inherit {    

    public int a = 3;
    private int b = 5;
    public class Inheriting {
        public int a = 23;
        private int d = 8;
        public void f() {
            System.out.println("Here I want to get a = 3");
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void f() {
    System.out.println("Here I want to get a = 3" + Inherit.this.a); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
Inherit.this.a;
```

But you'd better choose more descriptive names so that they don't clash.